# Dynamically creating mailchimp groups in a html form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, blogs, mailchimp

I want to create a mailchimp group from a html form on my page. How do I do this? I can only find ways to create groups from the mailchimp cms.

```
<div class="mc-field-group input-group">
   <strong>Select Group </strong>
<!-- insert php to create a new list of groups to pick from -->
   <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[14901][1]" id="mce-group[14901]-14901-0"><label for="mce-group[14901]-14901-0">Test 1</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[14901][2]" id="mce-group[14901]-14901-1"><label for="mce-group[14901]-14901-1">Test 2</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group[14901][4]" id="mce-group[14901]-14901-2"><label for="mce-group[14901]-14901-2">Test 3</label></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
```

My use case here is my blog, I want to have a new group users can sing up for per post.

I plan events via my blog posts, and if someone wants to sign up for an event they can add themselves to my mailing list and the mailchimp group will automatically be assigned based on the page they signed up from.

Comment: Mailchimp works with their api. As you posted, it's only html. Did you implement a php side which can communicate with the mailchimp api?

Answer (score 0):

As zeflex mentioned in that comment, this is something that will require the API, although I'm not sure the way you're thinking is the right approach. The thing that might trip you up, initially, is that each list is limited to 60 groups.

Since you'll also (probably) need to allow people to sign up for multiple groups, using a merge field is probably not ideal, either.

Instead, I would recommend using static segments. When a user signs up, you would use the API to add that user to a static segment for the blog post in question, creating it if it doesn't exist yet (and subscribing the user to the list, also, if necessary).

You'd probably want to store the segment ID for each post locally somewhere, if you can, to speed this process up.